# java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

My android app well work last month. but just upgrade

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'

->
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.0.2'

after

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.initialize(GoogleAccountCredential.java:144)
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:300)
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
                                                                     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
                                                                     at com.jhjg.skhu_drive.Controller.GoogleFileHelper$1.run(GoogleFileHelper.java:79)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

error point is `File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();`

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the calendar api. After some hours I added additionally the dependency:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'`

Then, the app worked again.